# Android single sign-on

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, single-sign-on

I'm getting **`login failed invalid key error`** while using an updated version of Facebook. If I delete it - it's working fine..

What is the correct way of **creating a hash key**?

I know that there are a lot of questions and answers for single sign on in Android, but none helped me to implement single sign-on in Android.

My code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("XXXXXXXXXX");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Then I generated a hash key using the command

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Also, I am having [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) and given the location of OpenSSL upto `openssl.exe`..

After I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> it is asking for a **password** and I gave **android** as the password. Then I got a key and filled in "My Application".

Answer (score 7):

**The correct way to create a hash key**

Please follow the following steps.

Here are the steps:

1. Download OpenSSL from [Google Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code)
2. Extract it. Create a folder- OpenSSL in `C:/` and copy the extracted code here.
3. detect the `debug.keystore` file path. If you don't find it, then do a search in `C:/` and use the path in the command in next step.
4. detect your `keytool.exe` path and go to that dir/ in a command prompt and run this command (in one line):

   `$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64`
5. it will ask for a password. Put "android", that's all. You will get a key-hash.

Answer (score 6):

First, you need to create the hash key using the below code according to your path.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Logistic103>keytool -export -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Logistic103\.android\debug.keystore" | E:\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | E:\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl.exe enc -a -e
```

Then enter the password:

```
Enter keystore password:  android
```

Then go to Facebook developers and login into Facebook. After login goto your application and click on edit setttings link:

[image]

Then add the generated key as under to your application,

[image]

And that's how you do it ;)

The above steps works well for me.

Comment: @Venky hi, I was having the same problem before 4-5 months and I finally solved it by following the above steps, but I remember that I had changes some code in facebook api but I dont remember it rit now, i ll revert u asap

Answer (score 0):

better use this piece of code

```
  try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.package",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("YOURHASH KEY:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link [Generate correct Hash Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889528/1179638)

You can generate Hash key problematically for both signed and unsigned app. And copy this key from your Logcat.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this might not be an answer, I guess you checked *[Android, the Facebook SDK, SSO, and You](http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/)*.

Are you using Windows XP for generating a hash? Maybe there lies the problem.

Comment: wel, it may not be an error of invalid key at all,
i had a similar error, of invalid access token...saying user might have changed his password...
but actually it was a different issue