# Error during Single Sign On

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I've built the code from [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) and it worked fine. But today the application asked me to aprove some unknown permissions(but i didnt add any permissons or anything else to my code) and showed error message after I clicked "ok" button:

Error detected in Appname. Please try again later.
API Error code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Requires valid redirect URI

What wrong with it? Where this redirect URI should be set?

PS: onCancel method of DialogListener is been calling during the error.

Update: I've found the issue on [facebook bug tracker.](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/205997112802034?browse=search_4e96d162dc4e64d27410796)

Comment: Can u Explain how you integrated SSO.. I have problem in in it.. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712361/android-single-sign-on

Comment: I have no idea! The described way works fine for me.

Comment: To all the people who want to know how to do things, I wrote this blog article: http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-facebook-integration.html some time ago (do tell me if it doesn't work) to demonstrate the stuff. it tries to explain how to do the things that Facebook has said. It would be a better idea to go through it rather calling him to chat room

Comment: @ArtemChilin That sounds weird. can you write to Facebook guys about this?

Comment: Do you mean facebook support or something like forum? I dont know where to write..

Comment: @SheikhAman Do you know how to generate correct Key hash?

Comment: @Venky your Android application's hash? of course I do know.

Comment: @Artem Chilin well, they have a bug report system, perhaps there. or on github!

Comment: @SheikhAman For Facebook Single Sign-On

Comment: Update: I've found the issue on facebook bug tracker.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/205997112802034?browse=search_4e96d162dc4e64d27410796

Comment: @ArtemChilin That's awesome. have they provided with any input on why this happens? the Android SDK of Facebook was created by one of their interns, not sure about its current development :P

Comment: but Josh Klobe wrote he faced the issue on iOS SDK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Enhanced Auth Dialog" should be disabled in application settings to solve the issue.

Removing the Facebook application updates could also help.