# Unable to use keytool and OpenSSL for Facebook Android SDK installation

Tags: android, facebook, keytool

I'm trying to create a Facebook integrated Android app, but trying to use Facebook's Android SDK is tiring. Here's [the tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#register) I'm following.

I'm stuck on the step **Using the Keytool**. I've searched around a bit and apparently I have to install OpenSSL which I promptly did.

I found keytool under these directories on my Windows machine:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0
```

---

When I run

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 from the tutorial on openssl
```

---

I get the following error:

```
openssl:Error: 'keytool' is an invalid command.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712361/android-single-sign-on   Check this

Comment: This should be your Java Bin path , if you set Java path no need to specify this path , directly you can try keytool ...

Comment: OpenSSL> Enter keystore password:  android
openssl:Error: '1τÖ3┴(6Kû1▀╛c(¿╪≡ñWU' is an invalid command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I followed Maulik J's post from the link provided by Venky [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712361/android-single-sign-on) and tried this command in the command prompt and it worked:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -export -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\MyUser\.android\debug.keystore" | C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe enc -a -e
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use keytool you need to have jdk installed  and also openssl need to be on your pc you can download it here
https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads

So currently i have mine here, so i have to cd to the directory

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13\bin>
```

And once i am in this directory i need to
run the command

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <alias>  -keystore "C:\Users\Codertjay\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Users\Codertjay\Downloads\Compressed\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\Codertjay\Downloads\Compressed\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

Notice that the path in here has my name on PC you need to update yours to the right path